# Best approach to take snapshots of specific data

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am having a DB table that contains orders, of which I need to take a snapshot on certain conditions. The idea behind it is as follows:
An order is opened -> all goods are assigned to the order -> the order is completed and an invoice is generated -> on order cancellation the order is staying open but a 'snapshot' of its last state is saved in DB (this could go for unlimited times, so I need any snapshot to be available, not to overwrite the last one) -> on the event of request of the same order (same client, same goods) the whole cycle repeats again..

**So my question goes:**

How should one implement it (I do not request code, but approaches and theory of operation)? what could the problems be in this kind of approach ?

***PS:*** I know that this question is tightly related to my own problem, and SO is not about that, but I desperately need help cuz I am really stuck.
Sorry!

Comment: don't use the php tag, your question got nothing to do with php... and the only reason why I was able to answer it is because I am not a php guy...

Comment: I did not mentioned PHP in the question, so that it could be as open as possible and not 'too localised'. Anyway ty for the tipo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something to **correctly model the order process**, you can have a 100 tables model or an elegant 1 single table model...

this database schema should sold your problem (a single table which track the order changes)

```
create table orderProcessFact
(order_id,
opened_date datetime,
goods_colected_date datetime,
payment_date datetime,
invoice_date datetime,
shipped_date datetime,
canceled_date datetime
);

create table order_items
(
order_id int
item_id int,
quantity int,
price numeric(5,3),
discount ...
)
```